# Is there a simplified cubic formula?

Tags: functions, polynomials

I'm trying to make a calculator of sorts for entering the values from a cubic function.

I found this website:
http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/
where it says that

"$$p = -b/(3a)$$

$$q = p3 + (bc-3ad)/(6a^2)$$
$$r = c/(3a)$$
"

and

"$$x   =   [q + [q^2 + (r-p^2)^3]^{1/2}]^{1/3}   +   [q - [q^2 + (r-p^2)^3]^{1/2}]^{1/3}   +   p$$"

But it seems to be only one of the roots. Which root(if any) exactly is this formula for, and what are the equations for the other 2, or 3 roots?

Comment: Wikipedia's entry on [cubic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) has more information about finding roots of a cubic than anyone is going to type into an answer here.

Comment: I don't actually understand any of the maths behind it, though, so that would be a bit of an issue.